# Following is my data file and i want to create a table what will be the delimiter?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using the following query for the data in hive.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aircel1 (subscriberID INT, towerID STRING, dataDownloaded STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/username/name';
```

What will be the delimiter when the data is as following.

```
subId=00001111911128052627towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212218.4621702216543667E17
    subId=00001111911128052639towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212219.6726312167218586E17
    subId=00001111911128052615towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212216.9431647633139046E17
    subId=00001111911128052615towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212214.7836041833447418E17
    subId=00001111911128052639towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212219.0366596827240525E17
    subId=00001111911128052619towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212218.0686280014540467E17
    subId=00001111911128052658towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212216.9860890496178944E17
    subId=00001111911128052652towerid=11232w34532543456345623453456984756894756bytes=122112212212212218.303981333116041E17
```

Comment: Use a hex editor to view if there's non printable characters separating it

Comment: You could consider using Regex

Comment: If possible, I would process the data in hadoop before reading it into Hive. For example, Java would grant you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Regex which will be along these lines (I haven't tested this)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aircel1 (
  subscriberID STRING, towerID STRING, dataDownloaded STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='subId=(.*)towerid=(.*)bytes=(.*)')
LOCATION '/user/username/dirname';
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach is a bit complicated for me as i am not well versed in what you are doing. But there is an error with your approach.

As i loaded the data LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/training/hive/UN.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE aircel1;

I have got the following error 

hive> select* from aircel1;
OK
NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL

Answer (score 0):

Using equal signs as a delimiter, you can build a table in two steps.

First, create a temporary table of all string columns.

For example, the first column would be the string `00001111911128052627towerid`.

Then you create your "real table" with the actual data types, and you can substring out the string `"towerid"`, for example, from the first column

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below code to complete the task,

```
create external table table1 (del string, subid string, towerid string, bytes double)

row format delimited
fields terminated by '='
location '/user/murali/';

create table table2 (subid string, towerid string, bytes double);

insert table table2 select 
    substring(subid,1,20),substring(towerid,1,41),bytes from table1;

select * from table2;
```

Comment: Great approach but i am getting following error can you please help me with it.

I have already done table1 and loaded data into table1 and getting following error on table2

hive> insert table table2 select                                          
    >  substring(subid,1,20),substring(towerid,1,41),bytes from table1;   
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'insert' 'table' 'table2' in insert clause